# Function returns &Option and not Option

Tags: rust

I am a beginner in Rust and I don't understand the behaviour I am encountering. Function number 1 should return me an Option type but returns an &Option type. I have worked around this by doing function 2 but I don't understand why this works. What am I doing wrong in my function?

**Function 1:**

```
pub fn manage_request(&self, request:String) -> Option<Some type> {
    let words : Vec<&str> = request.split_whitespace().collect();
    match words[0] {
        "attach" => &self.hashmap.get(words[1]),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

**Function 2:**

```
pub fn manage_request(&self, request:String) -> Option<Some type> {
    let words : Vec<&str> = request.split_whitespace().collect();
    match words[0] {
        "attach" => match &self.hashmap.get(words[1]){
            None => None,
            Some(x) => Some(x)
        }
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

[Here is a link to rust playground with the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0029e8eed74567395de4f38a7e5dc9fd)

Comment: if `self.tuple_spaces.get(..)` returns an `Option`, then `&self.tuple_spaces.get(..)` will return a `&Option`. The `&` is applied last to get a reference to a value. Simply remove it.

Comment: When I remove it, I got a "missing lifetime specifier" error

Comment: why does your playground function take `self` instead of `&self` like your question? my comment was only talking about the `self.tuple_spaces.get(..)` expression. It works if you only remove the one I mentioned ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05669e32c17075d6a78c221304cce2e3))

Comment: Thank you, I get it.I thought I had to remove it in the signature too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Correct me if Im wrong but I think you actually did this properly but might have missed a typo.

In your playground your signature *consumes* self by saying `fn manage_request(self)`. If you change this to take a reference to self like `fn manage_request(&self)` I believe it works.

Updated [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5a104cc02f1f4715f4420a8ff6da1f8) runs without compiler errors: